# Why only these numbers printed

Tags: c, pointers

Below is my code

```
main() 
{ 
 int c[ ]={2.8,3.4,4,6.7,5}; 
 int j,*p=c; 
 for(j=0;j<5;j++){ 
 printf(" %d ",*p); 
 ++p;   } 
}
```

The output was

```
2 3 4 6 5
```

How the above code is executed?

Comment: Use debugger with watch to see how variables are changing!

Answer (score 2):

it's executed exactly they way you think it's executed: you print the array elements in your `for` loop, however, you made the array elements as `int`, therefore, when printing `2.8` which is double, the compiler ignores whatever after the point, means, it sees it as 2 rather than 2.8

Answer (score 2):

When you write the statement :

```
 int c[ ]={2.8,3.4,4,6.7,5};
```

the decimal values are automatically converted to integers.So the array stores

```
  2,3,4,6,5
```

So your output becomes as it is. 
To work with decimals use float type variables.

```
  float c[ ]={2.8,3.4,4,6.7,5};
```

Answer (score 0):

The `int c[]` is integer.You can try it.

```
float c[] = { 2.8, 3.4, 4, 6.7, 5 };
float  *p = c;
for (int j = 0; j<5; j++){
    printf(" %f ", *p);
    p = p+1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use 'float j' instead of 'int j' and '%f' instead of '%d' you would get what you want.
Here due to the using of int j and %d, only the part before the decimal point of each number in the array is printed.